# Element f:event not expected. ADF

Tags: oracle-adf

I am trying to associate one f:event to a af:table in my fragment (jsff) as readed in other page.

This is the code:

```
< jsp:root xmlns:jsp="http://java.sun.com/JSP/Page" version="2.1" xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
          xmlns:af="http://xmlns.oracle.com/adf/faces/rich" >

    <af:table value="#{bindings.Departments.collectionModel}" var="row" rows="#{bindings.Departments.rangeSize}"
              emptyText="#{bindings.Departments.viewable ? 'No data to display.' : 'Access Denied.'}"
              fetchSize="#{bindings.Departments.rangeSize}" rowBandingInterval="0" id="t1">
```

Just below I want I put the line:

```
< f:event listener="#{managedBean.listenForEvent}" type="preRenderComponent"/ >
```

The problem is that I have an error in design time: Element f:event not expected. But I don´t know why, because in my version of JDeveloper 11g2.2.0 JSF 2.0 is included, and the element f:event belongs to the version 2.0.

Does anybody know why I cannot reference it?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you can't attach the f:event to the af:table as it's not know event for the table (in your release). This may change with 12c (not sure about this).

You can however surround the table with a panel group and put the event in the. This may help you archive your use case.

As you did not tell us what you are trying to do, we can't help here.

Answer (score 0):

This appears to be a bug in the design time then. Have you tried the runtime behavior? Does it work at runtime? JSF 2 system events are supported in JDeveloper 11g R2. So if the design time says different then the page source validation in the IDE is not correct. I'll verify with JDeveloper 11.1.2.2 and file a bug